# Matrix Multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I had any $m\times n$-matrix, where $m$ and $n$ are variables, what can I multiply this matrix by?

Can it be multiplied by itself?

By a square matrix?

Another $m\times n$-matrix?

Or can it be multiplied by a scalar?

Comment: To be complete, there are also [less common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Other_forms_of_multiplication) ways to multiply matrices, that aren't part of @Cameron's excellent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be multiplied componentwise by a scalar. It can be multiplied on the right by any $n$-row matrix, and on the left by any $m$-column matrix.

Comment: So it could be by a scalar? That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Yes, we can also multiply it by a scalar, though in general matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication are not the same thing. I would make a note that $m$ and $n$ should **not** be variables (as the dimensions of a particular matrix cannot change). Rather, they are some arbitrary fixed values (positive integers, specifically).

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$A\cdot B$ is defined, iff $A$ has as many *columns* as $B$ has *rows*

So, if $A$ is a $n\times m$-matrix and $B$ is a $m\times p$-matrix the product $A\cdot B$ is well-defined and the result is a $n\times p$-matrix.

---

Moreover you are allowd to multiply any matrix by a given scalar.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little to the answers here... there are a few details missing here but [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/week4.pdf) is a good reference for the details.

If the entries of your $m\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ lie in a ring $R$ (you can think $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ probably) then your matrix can be seen as a linear map, $T_A$:
$$T_A:R^n\rightarrow R^m\,,\,e_j\mapsto \sum_ia_{ij}e_i,$$

where $a_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-entry of $A$. That is $T_A$ takes in $n$-scalars and 'spits' out $m$.

You can show that the composition of linear maps as matrices is given by the ordinary matrix multiplication.

Now you can compose (multiply) with a linear map $T_B$ (matrix $B$) on the left or the right. Consider first on the left: $BA$. Now this is a linear map given by $T_B\circ T_A$:

$$R^n\underset{T_A}{\longrightarrow} R^m\underset{T_B}{\longrightarrow} V,$$

where $V$ is some vector space. If $B$ is to be a matrix with entries from $R$ then $V=R^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore we have:

$$R^n\underset{T_A}{\longrightarrow} R^m\underset{T_B}{\longrightarrow} R^k,$$

and so $A$ can be multiplied on the left only by a matrix $B$ that induces a linear map

$$T_B:R^m\rightarrow R^k;$$

i.e. $B$ is a $k\times m$ matrix. Therefore to multiply $B$ by $A$ on the left we have

$$\underbrace{B}_{k\times m}\quad\cdot\quad\underbrace{A}_{m\times n};$$

i.e. what the other answers said. Note that $T_B\circ T_A:R^n\rightarrow R^k$ so that $BA$ is a $k\times n$ matrix.

You can show that for multiplication on the right you need an $n\times k$ matrix.